# What happens with methods' tests when that method become private after re-design in TDD?

Tags: object-oriented-design, tdd

Let's say I start developing a role game with characters that attack other characters and that kind of stuff.

Applying TDD, I make some test cases to test the logic inside `Character.receiveAttack(Int)` method. Something like this:

```
@Test
fun healthIsReducedWhenCharacterIsAttacked() {
    val c = Character(100) //arg is the health
    c.receiveAttack(50) //arg is the suffered attack damage
    assertThat(c.health, is(50));
}
```

Say I have 10 methods testing `receiveAttack` method. Now, I add a method `Character.attack(Character)` (that calls `receiveAttack` method), and after some TDD cycles testing it, I make a decision: `Character.receiveAttack(Int)` should be `private`.

What happens with previous 10 test-cases? Should I delete them? Should I keep method `public` (I don't think so)?

This question is not about how to test private methods but how to deal with them after a re-design when applying TDD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing private methods as protected](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292087/testing-private-methods-as-protected)

Comment: If it's private you don't test it, it's that easy. Remove and do the _[refactor dance](https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/DLLM4wiXkAAs-iw.jpg)_

Comment: I'm probably going against the grain here. But, I generally avoid private methods at all costs. I prefer more tests than less tests. I know what people are thinking "What, so you never have any kind of functionality you don't want to expose to the consumer?". Yes, I have plenty I don't want to expose. Instead, when I have a private method I instead refactor it into it's own class and use said class from the original class. The new class can be marked as `internal` or your language's equivalent to still prevent it being exposed. In fact Kevin Cline's answer is this kind of approach.

Comment: I'd say that if the tests are valuable (and test framework didn't support testing private methods), I'd keep method public.

Comment: @user9993 you seem to have it backwards. If it's important for you to have more tests, the only way to ensure that you have not missed anything important is to run coverage analysis. And for coverage tools it doesn't matter at all if the method is private or public or whatever else. Hoping that making stuff public will somehow compensate for the lack of coverage analysis gives a false sense of security I'm afraid

Comment: @gnat But I never said anything about "not having coverage"? My comment about "I prefer more tests than less tests" should have made that obvious. Not sure what you are getting at exactly, of course I also test the code I've extracted. That's the whole point.

Comment: A common workaround in places that do TDD is to make all methods public, but have interfaces that don't include the "private" methods.  That's a pretty shitty workaround for not having a framework that can test private methods, though.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In TDD, the tests serve as executable documentation of your design. Your design changed, so obviously, your documentation must, too!

Note that, in TDD, the only way in which the `attack` method could have appeared, is as the result of making a failing test pass. Which means, `attack` is being tested by some other test. Which means that *indirectly* `receiveAttack` is covered by `attack`'s tests. Ideally, any change to `receiveAttack` should break at least one of `attack`'s tests.

And if it doesn't, then there is functionality in `receiveAttack` that is no longer needed and should no longer exist!

So, since `receiveAttack` is already tested through `attack`, it doesn't matter whether or not you keep your tests. *If* your testing framework makes it easy to test private methods, and *if* you decide to test private methods, then you can keep them. But you can also delete them without losing test coverage and confidence.

Comment: This is a good answer, save for "If your testing framework makes it easy to test private methods, and if you decide to test private methods, then you can keep them." Private methods are implementation details and should never, ever be directly tested.

Comment: @DavidArno: I disagree, by that reasoning the internals of a module should never be tested. However, the internals of a module can be of great complexity and therefore having unit-tests for each individual internal functionality can be valuable. Unit-tests are used to check the *invariants* of a piece of functionality, if a private method has invariants (pre-conditions/post-conditions) then a unit-test can be valuable.

Comment: "*by that reasoning the internals of a module should never be tested*". Those internals should never be *directly* tested. All tests should only test public APIs. If an internal element is unreachable via a public API, then delete it as it does nothing.

Comment: @DavidArno By that logic, if you're building an executable (rather than a library) then you should have no unit tests at all. - "Function calls are not part of the public API! Only command line arguments are! If an internal function of your program is unreachable via a command line argument, then delete it as it does nothing." -- While private functions aren't part of the public API of the class, they're part of the internal API of the class. And while you don't necessarily need to test the internal API of a class, you can, using the same logic for testing the internal API of an executable.

Comment: @R.M. "command line arguments" Also runtime input, etc.

Comment: @R.M., *if* I were to create an executable in a non-modular fashion, then I would be forced into choosing between brittle tests of the internals, or only using integration tests using the executable and runtime I/O. Therefore by my actual logic, rather than your strawman version, I would create it in a modular fashion (eg via a set of libraries). The public APIs of those modules can then be tested in a non-brittle fashion.

Comment: There could be valid reasons to test internals, but, if you are doing TDD, those tests are *not* the ones that document/describe your system, and become obsolete if the internals change. If you don't treat them that way, then they go against the very point of TDD and make refactoring difficult.

Comment: The danger here is introducing untested code, even if it was formerly tested. Sure behavior might be the same but do we now have a loss of code coverage? It is possible to exercise every branch of a private method through a public method that uses it but is that happening? Be sure it is before you blithely go ahead with this refactoring. Maybe there are parts of this private method that aren't needed anymore. Maybe new tests are now called for. Public and private methods are very different. Don't ask one to suddenly switch without considering a rewrite.

Comment: This kind of change is hard to do strictly under the test-first red-green-refactor cycle.  Fortunately there are alternative approaches that are just as reliable and formal. You can [refactor the test against the red bar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/341157/131624). The critical thing is to see the test both pass and fail. That way you're sure what is being tested.

Comment: Before you think about making refactoring harder / easier, you should think about getting your code to work properly in the first place. That's where tests are useful. Especially tests for private methods.

Comment: @DavidArno Does it not just come down to your definition of "module"? In some languages, a method can be invisible outside its "package", but visible to other classes within that package; is that method internal and tested only implicitly or an API that should be tested explicitly? It depends if you view the package as composed of multiple modules (the classes). Testing *certain* private methods is an extension of that grey area: functionality shared by several pieces of code within a module (class), but not published by the module (class) to the next layer up (package / component / library).

Comment: @IMSoP, "*in some languages, a method can be invisible outside its "package", but visible to other classes within that package; is that method internal and tested only implicitly*". That is correct. If it's not visible outside of the package, then it's an implementation detail and so should only be tested via a public API.

Answer (score 23):

If the method is complex enough to need testing, it should be public in some class. So you refactor from:

```
public class X {
  private int complexity(...) {
    ...
  }
  public void somethingElse() {
    int c = complexity(...);
  }
}
```

to:

```
public class Complexity {
  public int calculate(...) {
    ...
  }
}

public class X {
  private Complexity complexity;
  public X(Complexity complexity) { // dependency injection happiness
    this.complexity = complexity;
  }

  public void something() {
    int c = complexity.calculate(...);
  }
}
```

Move the current test for X.complexity to ComplexityTest. Then text X.something by mocking Complexity.

In my experience, refactoring toward smaller classes and shorter methods pays huge benefits. They are easier to understand, easier to test, and end up being reused more than one might expect.

Comment: Your answer explains much more clearly the idea I was trying to explain in my comment on OP's question. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, receiveAttack method is quite simple (`this.health = this.health - attackDamage`). Perhaps extract it to another class is an overengineered solution, for this moment.

Comment: This is definitely way overkill for the OP - he wants to drive to the store, not fly to the moon - but a good solution in the general case.

Comment: If the function is that simple maybe it's overengineering that it even is defined as a function in the first place.

Comment: "refactoring toward smaller classes and shorter methods pays huge benefits." - and if you take that to the ultimate limit of only one method per class, you can then throw away OOP and get back to doing Real Programming, not Quiche-eating ;)

Comment: it may be overkill *today* but in 6 month's time when there are a ton of changes to this code the benefits will be clear. And in any decent IDE these days surely extraction of some code to a separate class should be a couple of keystrokes at most hardly an over-engineered solution considering that in the runtime binary it will all boil down to the same anyway.

Answer (score 6):

> Say I have 10 methods testing receiveAttack method. Now, I add a method Character.attack(Character) (that calls receiveAttack method), and after some TDD cycles testing it, I make a decision: Character.receiveAttack(Int) should be private.

Something to keep in mind here is that the decision you are making is *to remove a method from the API*.  The courtesies of backwards compatibility would suggest

1. If you don't need to remove it, then leave it in the API
2. If you don't need to remove it *yet*, then mark it as deprecated and if possible document when the end of life will happen
3. If you do need to remove it, then you have a major version change

The tests get removed / or replaced when your API no longer supports the method.  At that point, the private method is an implementation detail that you should be able to refactor away.

At that point, you are back in the standard question of whether your test suite should be directly accessing implementations, rather interacting purely through the public API.  A private method is something that we should be able to replace *without the test suite getting in the way*.  So I would expect the tests couple to it to go away -- either getting retired, or moving with the implementation to a separately testable component.

Comment: Deprecation is not always a concern. From the question: "Let's say I start developing..." if the software is not released yet, deprecation is a non-issue. Furthermore: "a role game" implies this is _not_ a reusable library, but binary software aimed at end-users. While some end-user software does have a public API (e.g. MS Office), most does not. Even the software that _does_ have a public API only has a portion of it exposed for plugins, scripting (e.g. games with LUA extension), or other functions. Still, it is worth bringing up the idea for the general case that the OP describes.